# Why is my footer not going to the bottom of the page?

Tags: css, html

My footer on my page seems to not want to get to the bottom of the content (or the bottom of the screen).

How can I fix this?
https://www.algxchange.com/home

Comment: It seems fine on my end - I tested with IE8 and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

[A Bulletproof Sticky Footer, Woohoo!](http://css-tricks.com/sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 1):

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Perhaps the body still has the default spacing?

Also, it's recommended to use a doctype so your page is rendered in standards mode, not quirks mode ( anything goes, all hell breaks loose mode ).

And I assume you are already doing if not:

```
html, body { height:100%; } 
#wrapper { min-height:100%; margin-bottom:-50px; } 
#footer { margin-top:-50px; height:50px; }
```

`#wrapper` needs height:100% for IE6 since it doesnt support min-height.